# Chaining method calls with Either

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, either

I'd like to know if it is possible to create some kind of "method call chain", with all methods returning the same Either[Error,Result].

What i'd like to do is: call all the methods successively, and when method returns a Left(Error), then stop the method calls and return the first Left found in the call chain.

I've tryied some stuff, with fold, map, projections... but i'm new to Scala and don't find any elegant solution.

I've tryed some thing like that:

```
def createUserAndMandatoryCategories(user: User) : Either[Error,User] = {
    User.create(user).right.map {
      Logger.info("User created")
      Category.create( Category.buildRootCategory(user) ).right.map {
        Logger.info("Root category created")
        Category.create( Category.buildInboxCategory(user) ).right.map {
          Logger.info("Inbox category created")
          Category.create( Category.buildPeopleCategory(user) ).right.map {
            Logger.info("People category created")
            Category.create( Category.buildTrashCategory(user) ).right.map {
              Logger.info("Trash category created")
              Logger.info("All categories successfully created created")
              Right(user)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work.
And anyway i really don't like the indentation it takes.
Besides i'd like to transform the Error into a new String describing the problem (i guess i should use fold?)

I'm looking for something written like that:

```
val result : Either[String,CallResult] = call1.something("error 1 description")
.call2.something("error 2 description")
.call3.something("error 3 description")
.call4.something("error 4 description")
```

Is it possible to do such a thing with Scala? Perhaps using both Either and Option?

One constraint would also be that if the first call fails, the other calls should not be made. I don't want a solution where i call everything and then join the eithers.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Trait Validation from scalaz is what you are looking for

Comment: This is the description of the Either monad.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are better, more functional ways to do this (mostly involving Scalaz’s Validation and traverse/sequence) but your code is roughly equivalent to:

```
def createUserAndMandatoryCategories(user: User) : Either[Error,User] = for {
  _ <- User.create(user).right.map(Logger.info("User created")).right
  _ <- Category.create( Category.buildRootCategory(user) ).right.map(Logger.info("Root category created")).right
  _ <- Category.create( Category.buildInboxCategory(user) ).right.map(Logger.info("Inbox category created")).right
} yield user
```

Which at least gets rid of all the nesting. Since Scala’s `Either` is not right-biased by default, you have to specify that manually quite a few times, which reduces the readability a bit.

Comment: +1 nice on the right biasing, saw a thread on scala user (or scala debate) about right biasing either by default. I think for now we have to hand roll our own right bias either, or go with whatever Scalaz has cooked up in their latest & greatest

Comment: Scalaz is going to get `\/` (yes, that’s a type not a typo) which is supposed to be a right biased alternative.

Comment: Thanks will try this way, it seems to be what i'm looking for

Comment: Btw, can you explain why do i need to add the .right at the end of each for comprehension statement? I don't understand this part (but i understand the right.map(...) part)

Comment: There is no `map` on `Either` (and `_ <- ...` basically evaluates to `map`) so you have to say which side of the `Either` to use. (If `Either` were right-biased, you wouldn’t have that problem.)

Comment: According to [the 2.12 version documentation: `Either is right-biased, which means that Right is assumed to be the default case to operate on. If it is Left, operations like map, flatMap, ... return the Left value unchanged`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html). More details about the change can be found in [the official Scala 2.12 overview](http://scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0#either-is-now-right-biased).

Answer (score 6):

The [RightProjection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Either$$RightProjection) you're already using allows you to do exactly what you need using its `flatMap` method.

(By convention, computation results are stored in `Right` and error values for failed computations in `Left`. But there is no other reason, you could do the same with `LeftProjection`.)

Actually, what we have here is that `RightProjection` forms a monad. You can convert a value `x` into a projection using `Right(x).right`. And if you have a projection `p`, you can apply a possibly failing computation `f` on `p` by calling `p.flatMap(f)`. This way, you can chain several such methods.

This can be further simplified by `for` comprehensions. To give a complete example:

```
object EitherTest extends App {
  // we define some methods that can either fail 
  // and return a String description of the error,
  // or return a value

  def sqrt(x: Double): Either[String,Double] =
    if (x >= 0) Right(math.sqrt(x));
    else Left("Negative value " + x + " cannot be square-rooted.");

  // or you could have, if you want to avoid typing .right inside `for` later
  def sqrt0(x: Double): Either.RightProjection[String,Double] =
    ( if (x >= 0) Right(math.sqrt(x));
      else Left("Negative value " + x + " cannot be square-rooted.")
    ).right;

  def asin(x: Double): Either[String,Double] =
    if (x > 1) Left("Too high for asin")
    else if (x < -1) Left("Too low for asin")
    else Right(math.asin(x));


  // Now we try to chain some computations.
  // In particular, we'll be computing sqrt(asin(x)).
  // If one of them fails, the rest will be skipped
  // and the error of the failing one will be returned
  // as Left.

  { // try some computations
    for(i <- -5 to 5) {
      val input: Double = i / 4.0;
      val d: Either[String,Double] = Right(input);
      val result: Either[String,Double] =
        for(v <- d.right;
            r1 <- asin(v).right;
            r2 <- sqrt(r1).right
            // or you could use:
            // r2 <- sqrt0(r1)
        ) yield r2;
      println(input + "\t->\t" + result);
    }
  }
}
```

And the output is:

```
-1.25       ->      Left(Too low for asin)
-1.0        ->      Left(Negative value -1.5707963267948966 cannot be square-rooted.)
-0.75       ->      Left(Negative value -0.848062078981481 cannot be square-rooted.)
-0.5        ->      Left(Negative value -0.5235987755982989 cannot be square-rooted.)
-0.25       ->      Left(Negative value -0.25268025514207865 cannot be square-rooted.)
0.0         ->      Right(0.0)
0.25        ->      Right(0.5026731096270007)
0.5         ->      Right(0.7236012545582677)
0.75        ->      Right(0.9209028607738609)
1.0         ->      Right(1.2533141373155001)
1.25        ->      Left(Too high for asin)
```

Answer (score 2):

Debilski has "the" answer in going functional, but I'd trim it down further with some helper code:

```
// trait PackageBase (applicable package objects extend)
/*
 * not used in this example but can use below implicit to do something like:
 * for { x <- eitherResult as json }
 */
class RightBiasedEither[A,B](e: Either[A,B]) {
  def as[A1](f: A => A1) = e match {
    case Left(l)    => Left(f(l)).right
    case Right(r) => Right(r).right
  }
}
@inline implicit final def either2Projection[L,R](e: Either[L,R]) = new RightBiasedEither(e)

class Catching[T](f: => T) extends grizzled.slf4j.Logging {
  def either(msg: String) = { // add your own logging here
    try { Right(f).right }
    catch { case e: Exception => error( e.getMessage ); Left(msg).right }
  }
}
def catching[T](f: => T) = new Catching(f)

// in your query wrapper equivalent
protected def either[T](result: => T, msg: String)(implicit ss: Session) = {
  catching(result) either(msg)
}

// and then your DAO create methods will do something like:
def create(foo: Foo)(implicit ss: Session) {
  either[Int]( Foos.insert(foo), i18n("not created") )
}

// with the above code you can then strip things down to:
def createUserAndMandatoryCategories(user: User) : Either[Error,User] = {
  db.handle withSession { implicit ss: Session =>
    ss.withTransaction { 
      val result = for {
        _ <- User.create(user)
        _ <- Category.create( Category.buildRootCategory(user) )
        _ <- Category.create( Category.buildInboxCategory(user) )
      } yield user
      result fold ( e => { ss.rollback; Left(e) }, u => Right(u) )
    }
  }
}
```

In my take there is no need to log successful creation events (only the failures) since the entire transaction is rolled back on failure, but YMMV, add in logging as you like.

Comment: thanks will check that but i don't understand everything of your code :). Btw i don't need logging, just added it because i couldn't make the call chain return an appropriate error message

Comment: as everyone has pointed out, you need an Either projection in order to for{...} through a set of computations. This is one way to do it. All the query implicit Session stuff is ScalaQuery, BTW. You don't need the implicit RightBiasedEither class for this example, but comes in handy if you want to encode the Left error condition "val result = for{ x <- eitherResult as json }"