# Handling fail-fast failures when the return type is Option[Error]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have posted quite several questions about failure handling in Scala and I really thank you all for your answers.

I understand my options when dealing with Either and Scalaz or a for comprehension, and I have another (last?) question:

How to do a fail-fast sequence of operations when the operations are dealing with the outside non-functional world, like a DB?

---

I mean I have a method like that:

```
def insertItem(item: Item): Either[Error,Item]
```

Thanks to Either and these answers, I know how to do it with Either: [Chaining method calls with Either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12107272/chaining-method-calls-with-either) and 
[Method parameters validation in Scala, with for comprehension and monads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307965/method-parameters-validation-in-scala-with-for-comprehension-and-monads)

But my `Item` case class is immutable and it doesn't really make sense to return it as a `Right` since the caller already has the value.

Thus how can I do the same kind of thing with:

```
def insertItem(item: Item): Option[Error]
```

---

In my application, when an user is created, we also create some items for him.
If an item fails to create, then the whole process should stop.

When I use directly `Option[Error]` in a for comprehension, I don't think I'll get the result I expect.

I guess it makes sense to do something like that:

```
for {
  _ <- insertItem(item1).toLeft("???").right
  _ <- insertItem(item2).toLeft("???").right
  _ <- insertItem(item3).toLeft("???").right
}
```

But as the values "???" I put in my Right are never useful, I guess I'm missing the elegant solution which do not involve creating Rights that will never be used.

I think I'm looking for something that will continue the for comprehension only when the result is `None`, which is kind of weird because I just want to continue to the next operation, and not do a real `map` operation.

By the way, if possible, I would like both non-Scalaz and Scalaz solutions.
I'm not sure Scalaz handle such things, because it seems more focused on real functional programming and perhaps do not provide code for side-effect behaviors like my use case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see a principled reason not to use `Either[Error, Unit]` in a case like this (or at least I've done it, and I don't feel guilty about it). Say we have the following:

```
def launch(thing: String): Either[String, Unit] = Either.cond(
  thing.nonEmpty,
  println("Launching the " + thing),
  "Need something to launch!"
)
```

We can show that the right projection monad is appropriately lazy:

```
scala> for {
     |   _ <- launch("flowers").right
     |   _ <- launch("").right
     |   r <- launch("MISSILES").right
     | } yield r
Launching the flowers
res1: Either[String,Unit] = Left(Need something to launch!)
```

No missiles get launched, as desired.

---

It's worth noting that if you use `Option` instead of `Either`, the operation you're describing is just the sum given the "First" monoid instance for `Option` (where the addition operation is just `orElse`). For example, we can write the following with Scalaz 7:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def fst[A](x: Option[A]): Option[A] @@ Tags.First = Tag(x)

def launch(thing: String): Option[String] = if (thing.isEmpty) Some(
  "Need something to launch!"
) else {
  println("Launching the " + thing)
  None
}
```

And now:

```
scala> val r: Option[String] = fst(launch("flowers")) |+| fst(
     |   launch("")) |+| fst(launch("MISSILES"))
Launching the flowers
r: Option[String] = Some(Need something to launch!)
```

Once again, no missiles.

Answer (score 3):

We do something similar where I work with scalaz to fail fast with message sending, though this is not idiomatic scalaz:

```
def insertItem(item: Item): Validation[Error, Unit]

val result = for {
  _ <- insertItem(item1)
  _ <- insertItem(item2)
  _ <- insertItem(item3)
} yield Unit
```

Comment: I think the Scalaz Validation is a list of errors and not only one error, and it's not fail-fast right?

Comment: @SebastienLorber Validation's flatMap method is fail-fast.  The Applicative instance accumulates.

Comment: There is also the Scalaz Either type (`\/`) that is just a more reasonable version of `scala.Either`.

Comment: @Huw can you provide an exemple of how to use it with such a case please? \/ is kind of hard to search in Google

Comment: `def insertItem(item: Item): Error \/ Unit; val result = for { _ <- insertItem(item1); _ <- insertItem(item2); _ <- insertItem(item3) } yield Unit`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to chain together methods that contain `Option[Error]` and only execute the next step if the `Option` is `None`, you can use `orElse` for that.

Comment: This is a nice idea that i didn't though about. It works fine with lazy eval of the following operations. The only problem is the strange readability

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the first failure, than an `Iterator` can be your choice:

```
case class Item(i: Int)

case class Error(i: Item)

val items = Iterator(1,3,7,-5,-2,0) map Item

def insertItem(item: Item): Option[Error] =
  if (item.i < 0) Some(Error(item)) else None

scala> val error = (items map insertItem find (_.isDefined)).flatten
error: Option[Error] = Some(Error(Item(-5)))
```

If `insertItem` is not your only method it is possible to call them separated with your values:

```
val items = Iterator(
  () => insertItem(i1),
  () => deleteItem(i2),
  () => insertItem(i3),
  () => updateItem(i4))
```